# Non-default constructor for C++ class which is a member of another class?

Tags: c++, constructor

This is a question about constructors. Two C++ classes A and B are related conceptually as

```
class A
{
  B b;
};

class B
{
  A *a;
};
```

The question is, when an instance of A is created, I want its member B to be constructed with a pointer to A. So it seems B requires a constructor that has a pointer to an instance of A as an argument, and that that constructor of B be invoked when an instance of A is constructed, rather than the default constructor of B.

Is there a simple way to do this?

Comment: Define said c'tor? What's the problem exactly?

Comment: To start with, you need a forward declaration to do that...

Answer (score 1):

Using `struct` here just for the public defaults.

```
struct A;

struct B {
    B(A *a_ptr = 0) : a(a_ptr) {}
    A *a;
};

struct A {
    A() : b(this) {}
    B b;
};
```

You might get a warning in the constructor for `A` from a busybody compiler that `this` points to an object that has not been fully constructed.

Comment: You could add that `struct A a; std::cout << (a.b.a == &a) << std::endl;` will print `1` to make this usage clearer, and prove that it works: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RYxNCsMgFIT3nmKgULSQkHV@CuYixai0QmKC0W5Czm6NLelbzbz5ZuSyFE8pY7wYK8egNFozr95pMd0JSSJID96cssdGkK6nHDfxWLxDh4qhhqDZMmx7Jo68Ifu/yn9VTg98oP5l1pPuMXxhYz0mYSx9z0axXDn7aS9bVddyDh5tCyrKoRToOlwFOx451VaNmXXaB2dRpe0YPw "C++ (gcc) – Try It Online")